# Why when I install my apps APK on Physical Android Device says App Not Installed

Tags: android, flutter, apk

Attention great developers.

I have hit a snag. I have built this application in flutter and has been in development for over a year. When I run the command flutter build apk the apk file is built and located in the Outputs file within the build. When I transfer the apk to my device and install it gives a App not installed.
How can I debug this or has anyone had this issue and knows how to solve it. I am worried that it might have something to do with my flutter_google_maps pacakge.

Anyone help and guidance is much appreciated.

I will attach a screen shot of the error.
Cheers[image]

Comment: Is your apk signed?

Comment: Hey Mate. No the apk is not signed. I just wanted a simple apk that my users can install on their android devices.

Comment: Signing is a requirement on Android. Make sure to sign your app with apksigner so it's signed with v2 scheme (a requirement on latest Android version)

Comment: Hey Mate. I made a default app with the same settings and built the apk. This apk was able to be installed so I can confidently say that is not the issue unfortunately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After another day of debugging I have found the issue. The problem was the assets folder with the images. Once I removed all images not being used the apk install worked. Hopefully this helps others.

Cheers Everyone for the contributions

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is with the apps package name. You should check if the any other app is installed in the device with the same package name. Try uninstalling the previous if exist.

Hope this would help you.

Comment: Hey Mate. No other application on my device is labelled the same and I have had two coworkers try to install on their devices. They both got the same result. Do you think if I made a new solution named something simple would fix this? Cheers for trying to help.